# Is client aware of endorsing peers through which it makes a transaction proposal in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

Is client aware of endorsing peers through which it makes a transaction proposal? If yes, how does it know or where is it configured ?, If No, then which peer first take a proposal to endorse the Transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, client should be aware of the endorsing peers that it will send proposal to while fabric-sdk(node, java, python, etc...) is not aware of the endorsing peers. fabric-sdk just sends proposal to the endorsing peers list that the client told it. Please notice that fabric-sdk is just part of your client application.
You can refer to the example [invoke chaincode](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/test/integration/e2e/e2eUtils.js#L521-L535)